# Change the position of div window is resizing

Tags: jquery, html, css

hi all i have two div's latestnews,slider

```
<div id="topcontent">
  <div id="latestnews"> Content1  </div>
  <div id="slider">   content2   </div>
</div>
```

and i use the following css for that

```
#topcontent {
  height:auto;
  margin-top:15px;
  overflow:hidden;
 }
#latestnews {
width:32%;
float:left;
height:auto;
}

#slider {
margin:0 33%;
width:67%;
position:relative;

}

@media handheld, only screen and (max-width: 767px) {

#latestnews {
    float:none;
    width:100%;    }
 #slider {
    margin:0;
    width:100%;    }
 }
```

when width reached in 767px content 1 place first and then content2 place, actually need to place content2 first when the width reaches 767px. how it possible to rearrange the div in different width. please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Try **position property** and **floating to left**.

```
@media handheld, only screen and (max-width: 767px) {

  #latestnews {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
  }

  #slider {
    margin:0;
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    position:absolute;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **float** also in `#slider` instead of `margin: 0 33%;`

```
#slider {
/*margin:0 33%;*/
float: right;
width:67%;
position:relative;

}
```

Comment: but the positions in less width is no changed as my need

Comment: if so just enable margin and remain the float

Answer (score 0):

Use `Float:right`property to achieve this

http://jsfiddle.net/Lubuu/7/ Demo

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way of doing it using absolute positioning.

```
@media handheld, only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    #topcontent {
        position: relative;
    }
    #latestnews {
        margin: 51px 0 0 0;
        width: 100%;
        color: red;
    }
    #slider {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        margin:0;
        width: auto;
        height: 50px;
        display: inline-block;
        border: 1px dotted blue;
    }
}
```

If you have a slider, you may have a fixed height.  If that is the case, absolute position the `#slider` to the top of the parent block and then add a top margin to the `#latestnews` element to avoid overlapping the elements.

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/8mJNV/

Alternatively, you could use JavaScript or jQuery to rearrange the DOM elements and then use floats.